# What is the difference between SPI,SCI and SDI?

Tags: microcontroller, audio, spi, arm

Hi I'm trying to interface an audio codec chip [VS1053B](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1681)  with my [STM32L476](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/02/35/09/0c/4f/f7/40/03/DM00083560.pdf/files/DM00083560.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00083560.pdf) Microcontroller. But in the microcontroler there is SPI interface and in the VS1053B  chip it is SCI interface with few extra pins as,
XCS  - Send Command (Active Low)  ,
XDCS - Send Data (Active Low),
XRST - Reset (Active Low),
DREQ - Data Request.

What is the purpose of these pins? is it possible to interface this IC using SPI? What are the major differences between the interfaces, SPI,SCI and SDI??

Comment: Hmm skimming over the datasheet it looks like normal SPI with a CS-pin for commands and a CS-pin for data, probably to reduce the protocol overhead when streaming data.

Answer (score 1):

In the descrition of the VS1053B on Adafruit you can see that there is :

- SPI flash boot for special applications
- UART for debugging purposes
- **Serial control** and data interfaces

And [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/324565/spi-vs-sci-on-ti-processor) there is a response about SCI :

> SCI is not a standard term. Usually it's called a UART, and that's the
>   interface you would use to communicate between the dev board and the
>   PC. SPI is used for communication between chips on a board, supports
>   higher speeds, and has a single master clock. UARTs are used for
>   longer distances, each side asynchronously transmits their own data
>   such that the clock can be recovered from it, and is usually
>   transmitted at speeds just necessary for human interface devices such
>   as keyboards.

So SCI is a sort of UART and you can find more infos here : http://www.ece.utep.edu/courses/web3376/SCI%20Overview.html

Answer (score 0):

This section from the datasheet is useful -

[image]